# JSF Displaying multiple custom but similiar objects - can't pass a parameter?

Tags: jsf-2, parameters

My application needs to create several objects on a (JSF) webpage. I've got it working but this seems like a crazy approach.  Here is a really simplified snippet to show what I'm doing:

```
< div class="#{colorBean.colorMethod}"></div>
< div class="#{colorBean.increment}"></div>
< div class="#{colorBean.colorMethod}"></div>
```

Ideally I'd like to just pass in an index, thus something like:
    < div class="#{colorBean.colorMethod(3)}">
But of course JSF has a fit about trying to do that.
I'm using a getIncrement() method in a dummy DIV that displays nothing just to advance (increment) to the next object I want to work with.  (not to mention that to use it like this I can't just declare a method "public void increment() {}" but I have to use the get naming convention and I have to return a String which I ignore)

There has to be a better way!

Comment: I think it would be useful to know what HTML you want to render at final, if you only want an even/odd color change, you can do it in CSS.

Comment: With EL 2.2 or above, your approach of sending a parameter via `#{colorBean.colorMethod(3)}` would work. But in this case you might want to send a ordered list or an array of possible colorMethods `String[] colorMethods = {"method1", "method2", "method3"}` and then access them from the JSF either via a datatable, `<ui:repeat />` (if you use Facelets) or simply via `#{colorBean.colorMethod[1]}`. For a more accurate solution, I need more input.

Comment: Alexandre, no, not just odd/even color - it's a complex object with several properties and I need to adjust background colors as well as display different text.

Comment: L-Ray, I'm actually implementing a new approach using ui:repeat to fetch the objects one at a time from a list.  Thanks. (it wasn't clear to me previously how to mix JSF components and HTML elements but I've got it working)